# Linpeas does not work with this error: peass{VARIABLES}: not found

Tags: bash

I want to use linpeas script to scan for privilege esclation vulnerabilities but the linpeas.sh does not work with this error: peass{VARIABLES}: not found.
Since my machine does not internet, I just copied the linpeas.sh from the git and paste the code on a file on my machine. in the past it was working but I wanted to scan again and now I see this error, I have the same problem on RedHat and Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: This is a markup intended to be processed by the linPEAS "builder" python scripts (see [sensitive_files.yaml, line 107](https://github.com/carlospolop/PEASS-ng/blob/master/build_lists/sensitive_files.yaml)). You probably downloaded `linpeas_bash.sh` from the project's `linPEAS >> builder >> linpeas_parts` subdirectory. Instead you should probably download the `linpeas.sh` file from the [releases](https://github.com/carlospolop/PEASS-ng/releases/tag/20240204-ab87b191) page.